# sql query to get only one name if id exists in both table with different records

Tags: sql

Thanks in advance, I have two tables one is users table and another one is checks table. users table contain all users list and checks table contains all the data checked by the users so it contain rows with different adminids. So how to write a sql query to get the user name if the checks table contain atleast one adminid.

**My users table:**

```
id |username |Phone     |email            |role 
 1 | Girish  |9834343468|girish@yahoo.com |admin
 2 | Rakesh  |9434343432|rakesh@gmail.com |admin
 3 | Suresh  |9434343772|suresh@gmail.com |developer
```

**checks table:**

```
id | userid | username | admin_id |order_id |exam |
1  | 3      | suresh   | 1        | df54545454fg09|
2  | 3      | suresh   | 1        | df54545454fg09|
3  | 3      | suresh   | 2        | gh54995454fg55|
```

I need a sql query where atleast one "admin_id" of checks table contain users table "id"

I want to create a table like this

```
id|admin_id|name   |email            |Phone
1 |   1    |Girish |girish@gmail.com |9834343468
2 |   2    |Rakesh |rakesh@gmail.com |9434343432
```

Comment: What is your approach?

Comment: This is a very simple scenario. This can be achieved in different ways.Try googling about JOIN, Sub-query.

Comment: No actually join, left join, right join will combine both table data and displays the result . Instead of this i need a distinct id of users present in checks table as "admin_id"

Comment: In that case use `Distinct` and `JOIN` at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query

```
SELECT u.id,a.admin_id,u.username name, u.email, u.Phone
FROM users u,
(SELECT DISTINCT admin_id
FROM checks c) a
WHERE u.id=a.admin_id
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u.id,a.admin_id,u.username name, u.email, u.Phone
from users u
(select c.admin_id
from checks c
group by c.admin_id) a
where u.id=a.admin_id
```

Comment: admin_id is not present in users table so i changed the the sql query like this select id,username,email,phone
from users u
(select admin_id
from checks
group by admin_id) a
where u.id=a.admin_id

Comment: @RagithThomas No Admin_id is coming from subquery "a"

Comment: @RagithThomasI have edited response..Try that , if error comes tell me exactly which error you are getting

Comment: I am getting error like this #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select admin_id
from checks
group by admin_id) a
where u.id=a.admin_id
LIMIT 0' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM User_table WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM admin_table WHERE id = admin_id)
```

Try this
 SELECT id,admin_id,A.username name,email,Phone
FROM User_table 
JOIN
(
 SELECT DISTINCT Admin_Id,username
 FROM admin_table
) A ON A.Admin_Id = id

Comment: No Mansoor it's not working, i need only distinct admin_id of checks table which is present in users table id